# Is there any website/api from where windows phone apps downloads statistics can be fetched

Tags: android, windows

I want to know how downloads statistics of a [windows phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store) application's can be seen or retrieved. Something similar to the total downloads of android apps in play store.

Comment: can you rephrase your question clearly?

Comment: i just want to know the how many times a windows mobile app is downloaded i.e there total number of downloads. http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store

Comment: you want to find windows downloads in android?

Comment: nops i just gave an example that like  we can know that how many times an android app is installed from playstore (e.g a graph is shown in this link which show stats of install https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devontrix.tictactoe#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLmRldm9udHJpeC50aWN0YWN0b2UiXQ..) but in windows mobile app store http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store i cannot see any stats which tell me how many time an app is downloades it only show reviews.

Answer (score 0):

When you register as a developer and you publish an app, you can see how many times *your* application was downloaded (if I am not mistaking). I don't think it is possible to see how many times someone else's app was downloaded from the marketplace.

Hope this helps